# How do I compile a WCF Service Library in 32-bit mode?

Tags: wcf

I can reference Matlab code from a x86 based project, but not from an x64 project.

I can build the WCF Service as "Any CPU", but not x86. When I attempt to build as x86 only, it gives the following error:

```
---start error---
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\backtest\WcfServiceLibrary.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
---end error---
```

Thus, I'm stuck: how on earth do I provide Matlab calls via WCF? Its like some weird form of developers XOR.

Any ideas on how to either (a) compile the WCF Service Library in 32-bit mode, or (b) work around the issue?

I have Win7 x64, MSVS 2010.

Comment: By default, `WcfSvcHost.exe` is 64-bit, so it only runs 64-bit assemblies and will throw errors with 32-bit assemblies. If you can avoid hosting using `WcfSvcHost.exe`, then you avoid errors associated with trying to use 32-bit assemblies. There are ways to host a WCF service that avoids `WcfSvcHost.exe`, which solves the original issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WcfServiceLibrary is a DLL, so should be built as "Any CPU". Only EXE projects hosting all the other DLLs need to be marked as "x86" or "x64" as required. Which project is the EXE in this case?

Comment: The client is the EXE. The EXE calls functions of the WCF web service, the WCF service calls the Matlab functions in turn. I understand that DLL's need to be marked as "Any CPU", but if I do this, then I can't instantiate the Matlab class to call Matlab functionality as it gives an error.

Comment: Presumably the client is actually using a proxy to the WCF service. So what is hosting the WCF service - IIS, a console app, or a Windows service?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for putting me on the right track. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755761/i-cant-compile-a-standard-wcf-service-library-in-x86-format. I had a solution with two projects: one project was a console app which consumes services from the WCF Service Library, and one project was the WCF Service Library. When I ran the console app, it automatically executed the service, hosted with "WcfSvcHost". I've demonstrated that if I host my 32-bit WCF Service Library using a different method, namely IIS, it won't throw any exceptions just because its compiled in 32-bit mode.

Comment: This link explains more about the methods to host WCF services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic3

Answer (score 27):

Your problem is actually the WCF Test Client complaining that your WCF Service Library is 32bit. This is because by default, the WCF Test Client always runs in 64 bit mode.

I found the following steps on this [blog](http://www.develop-one.net/blog/CommentView,guid,5b290b3d-3487-48c6-bf18-5fc1882f6200.aspx#commentstart) which makes the WCF Test Client run in 32bit mode - and therefore you will not see the error you have posted.

1. Copy WcfSvcHost.exe and WcfTestClient.exe from C:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE to a local directory. Keep a backup copy of this file, of course.
2. Start a Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt (one of the links from the start menu -> Visaul Studio 2010)
3. "cd" to the directory where your copy of WcfSvcHost is located.
4. Execute the command "corflags /32BIT+ /FORCE WcfSvcHost.exe"
5. Execute the command "corflags /32BIT+ /FORCE WcfTestClient.exe"
6. Copy the files back to where you found it.

Now your WcfSvcHost and WcfTestClient will be running in 32 bit mode, and you won't get your error

Comment: Related [article with screens](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/04/debugging-a-wcf-service-using-a-32-bit-dll/) says how to preserve original .exe and how to configure VS to use 32bit copies of the Host and Client apps.

Comment: You should note that since following this steps, `WcfSvcHost` and `WcfTestClient` will always run in x86.

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of good solutions which solved all my problems. I documented it here:
[I can't compile a standard "WCF Service Library" in x86 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755761/i-cant-compile-a-standard-wcf-service-library-in-x86-format)