# System.Data.Sqlite.dll 32 bt vs 64 bit c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, x86, windows-7-x64

I have a WCF service library built using c# and system.data.sqlite.dll x64. The build configuration is Any CPU. It works fine. But when I change the system.data.sqlite.dll to a x86 bit version, for Any CPU configuration it builds successfully but when I run wcf methords it gives error, for x86 build configuration it build successfully but give following error when I debug it using wcftestclient.

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\lala\Desktop\New folder\New folder\CoreServiceWCF\CoreServiceWCF\CoreServiceWCF2\bin\x86\Debug\VplusCoreServiceWCF.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'file:///C:\Users\lala\Desktop\New folder\New folder\CoreServiceWCF\CoreServiceWCF\CoreServiceWCF2\bin\x86\Debug\VplusCoreServiceWCF.dll'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.LoadServiceAssembly(String svcAssemblyPath)

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = lala-PC\lala
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Users\lala\Desktop\New folder\New folder\CoreServiceWCF\CoreServiceWCF\CoreServiceWCF2\bin\x86\Debug\VplusCoreServiceWCF.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/lala/Desktop/New folder/New folder/CoreServiceWCF/CoreServiceWCF/CoreServiceWCF2/bin/x86/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\lala\Desktop\New folder\New folder\CoreServiceWCF\CoreServiceWCF\CoreServiceWCF2\bin\x86\Debug\VplusCoreServiceWCF.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/lala/Desktop/New folder/New folder/CoreServiceWCF/CoreServiceWCF/CoreServiceWCF2/bin/x86/Debug/VplusCoreServiceWCF.dll.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

An anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: 32 and 64 bit executables are not compatible.  32 bit programs cannot load 64 bit DLLs and vice versa.  This is, to my knowledge, a universal restriction (i.e. it won't work on any platform).

Comment: ya that's right. My simple question is I can't get my wcf work with system.data.sqlite.dll 32 bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an assembly is built for Any CPU it will take the best configuration of the computer you run, that means that it will run in 64 bits mode if you have a 64 bits Windows and it will run in 32 bits mode if it's in a 32 bits Windows, the problem seems to be this assembly: VplusCoreServiceWCF.dll, so i would recommend you yo check the bitness of this assembly first and see if it's the correct one (in your case probably is 64 bits)

Edit: Digging around i found that the WCF Test Client only runs in 64 bits mode, so you may need to force it to 32 bits, for this you can find the needed information here: [I can't compile a standard "WCF Service Library" in x86 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755761/i-cant-compile-a-standard-wcf-service-library-in-x86-format)

Comment: VplusCoreServiceWCF.dll is the build result of this wcf service library project. I get the above error when I try to debug it using wcftestclient.

Comment: You need to force WCF Test Client to run in 32 bits mode, check the edit.

Comment: yeagh That's really help full, Thanks for the answer Rafael :)