# WCF service library : BadImageFormatException with 32 bit dll

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

My project Structure looks like this:

```
 myApp 
 -->WCFSerLib (Any CPU Deafult application) 
 -->ClassLib1 (Any CPU)
 -->ClassLib2 (x86)
```

When I try to execute my application Unfortuantely am getting this below error.

```
 System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled by user code
```

Is there anyway such that I can achieve the above?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using nativ dll files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys,

problem was with **winscard.dll** it uses Handles which are Int32
.all I changed is replacing the **Int32** with **Int64**.

Answer (score 4):

If I guess right than you are trying to use an x86 dll on a x64 mashine. With AnyCPU the .net framework will use the currient architecture automatically.

So your application runs as a x64 Application which tries to load a x86 libary which failes. So you have two options:

- Set the target architeture to x86
- Add/create a x64 libary

If you have both verions (x86/x64) somewhere in you envireonment variable the operation system will choos the correct one automatically.

Comment: I dont think WCFService Library  supports x86

Comment: Icant set it to x86 as WCFLibrary allows only x64.. Second point Have created the Classlib2.dll 64bit lib but the same the underlying dependant dll is in 32 Bit.

Comment: In this case you need to get rid of your x86 dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are running your application on a x64 system.
Mixing the Platform Type in that way will cause the BFE when the WCFService Library or the ClassLib1 call methods in ClassLib2 because the first two run as 64bit processes while the latter is forced to run in x86 mode.

You should set the same platform type on every project.
Of course, the WCFService library supports only AnyCPU, so it make sense to use, for every project, the AnyCPU platform type.

If your ClassLib2 requires the use of a 32bit library (winscard.dll) and there is no 64bit version of that library, then, I think you should use a WCF Service Application instead of a Service Library. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755761/i-cant-compile-a-standard-wcf-service-library-in-x86-format)

Comment: Agreed Only problem for me setting `CLassLib2` into Any CPU type is that I use winscard.dll in this classlib2.dll which for some reasons giving me issues with 64-Bit.

Comment: I was just looking for this, I don't know if there is a 64 bit version of that DLL. If not, then I think you should use a WCF Service Application instead of Service Library.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755761/i-cant-compile-a-standard-wcf-service-library-in-x86-format

Comment: I even thought the same steve.. Lastly can I host a WCF service application as a windows service?

Comment: Found [this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.100).aspx), but I don't know if you could avoid the 64bit limitation of a Service Library. Need to search more.